# Best way to turn in a java project: Maven vs Simple java project

Tags: java, maven

Here is my situation: I am turning in a coding challenge for an interview. We are allowed to use any programming language, I chose Java. I completed the project and it provides the correct output, but I am stuck on some technicalities of turning it in. The spec says that it will be compiled and run using the terminal on a mac or linux machine, and it says to "turn in source code only, please do not include compilation artifacts or binary dependencies". I have a couple jars as dependencies. Does this mean I can't include them with my source code? How would they compile the program then. Right now I am not using any management tool. I could use Maven and declare the dependencies in the pom.xml, but then I have to assume whoever grades my solution has Maven installed to run "mvn".

Should I stick with a basic java project and include the jars, use Maven instead, or is there another better way to do this? Sorry if I am overthinking this, I want to make it simple to run my project so my work can be assessed for its accuracy, not how I packaged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't include any dependencies as JARs. You need to use Maven or Gradle for this.

You don't need to assume that Maven is installed, [Maven Wrapper](https://reflectoring.io/maven-wrapper/) can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide mvnw, what stands for maven wrapper. It's project-local installation of maven that is treated as source code and is used by calling `./mvnw` instead of global `mvn` command (to make it working for the first time, use `mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper`). [Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper).